# How to write case logic in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where i want to write SQL case logic for below

*Not understanding when to make use of symbol `'<>'`*

**Logic 1 :**

```
if [ employee_name] = 'ABC' then
empcode='ABC'
empcourse=Null
```

**Logic 2 :**

```
if [ employee_name] <> 'ABC' then
empcode='PQR-N'
empcourse='MBA'
```

**Below is the query i tried writing :**

```
case
    when employee_name equal ABC and empcode equal 'ABC'
    then 
    empcode='ABC'
    empcourse=Null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two `case` expressions.  I think you want:

```
(case when employee_name = 'ABC' then 'ABC' else 'PQR-N' end) as empcode,
(case when employee_name = 'ABC' then NULL else 'MBA' end) as empcourse
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only provide the value for one column in the select list at a time; therefore, you must handle the `empcode` value separately from `empcourse`.

Your logic can be represented as:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN employee_name = 'ABC'
  THEN 'ABC'
  WHEN employee_name <> 'ABC'
  THEN 'PQR-N'
  ELSE NULL
END AS empcode,
CASE
  WHEN employee_name = 'ABC'
  THEN NULL
  WHEN employee_name <> 'ABC'
  THEN 'MBA'
  ELSE NULL
END AS empcourse
```

This is because there is a third case when `employee_name` is `NULL` and then `employee_name = 'ABC'` will be false and `employee_name <> 'ABC'` will also be false; to be explicit about your output in this third case you can test for the first two and then use an `ELSE` condition.

The first expression could be written even more explicitly (and verbosely) as:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN employee_name IS NOT NULL AND employee_name = 'ABC'
  THEN 'ABC'
  WHEN employee_name IS NOT NULL AND employee_name <> 'ABC'
  THEN 'PQR-N'
  ELSE -- employee_name IS NULL
       NULL
END AS empcode,
CASE
  WHEN employee_name IS NOT NULL AND employee_name = 'ABC'
  THEN NULL
  WHEN employee_name IS NOT NULL AND employee_name <> 'ABC'
  THEN 'MBA'
  ELSE -- employee_name IS NULL
       NULL
END AS empcourse
```

If you intention is to use only two states (binary logic, rather than having a third `NULL` state) then:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN employee_name = 'ABC'
  THEN 'ABC'
  ELSE -- employee_name IS NULL OR employee_name <> 'ABC'
       'PQR-N'
END AS empcode,
CASE
  WHEN employee_name = 'ABC'
  THEN -- employee_name IS NULL OR employee_name <> 'ABC'
       NULL
  ELSE 'MBA'
END AS empcourse
```

Comment: can you write some comments parallelly after every SQL line will get to know what value it will return to column

Comment: according to given logic in question which one should i use first query or second query … exact query ?

Comment: @codeholic24 If you are dealing with trinary logic such as when `employee_name` can have the three states: either (as pseudo-code) `(IS NOT NULL AND = 'abc')` or `(IS NOT NULL AND <> 'abc')` or else `IS NULL` then use the first query. When you want two possible states: `= 'abc'` or else `IS NULL OR <> 'abc'` then use the second query.